# Disabling quotas on Linux

Tags: linux, vps, quota

I am in a situation where the root user is kind of in a locked situation due to exceeded quotas. I am unable to eedit /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab to remove the quota tag in the file for root.

Is there a work around? I can't boot to single-user mode& make any changes as this is a VPS.

Comment: A VPS doesn't by itself prevent you from booting single user.  Have you checked with your provider, whether they provide a console session?